# Ajax call to Rest service not successfully calling success function in ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, rest

I am having some ajax difficulties (and am newish to ajax, but have done a fair bit of searching) when calling a java rest server that I have written.  I have a test html page running within the Rest server (using Jetty) and I use the following call -- which works successfully using a .get:

```
        $('#getRVLakeForm').submit(function(e) {
            var handle = $('#insertRVLakeHandle').val();
            var lakekey = $('#RVLakeKey').val();
            var temp = $('#RVLakeTemp').val();
            var speed = $('#RVLakeWindspeed').val();
            var degrees = $('#RVLakeWindDegrees').val();;
            $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/recent/lake/' + handle + "/" + temp + "/" +  speed + "/" + degrees + "/" + lakekey, function(data) {
                alert(data.lake[0].oid);

                $('#RMLakeResponse').text("back");
            });
```

Here is the JSON the Rest server returns:

{"user":[],"lake":[{"oid":"519b9a1a3004f8fa1287502a","type":"Lake","handle":"nightstalker","viewedhandle":"","viewedlaketag":"TXFORK","viewedusername":"","timestamp":1369152026668}]}

This call executes the Rest Api and gets JSON back as expected...  When I attempt to call the same Rest Api from HTML/PHP application, running under MAMP -- the ajax call works on the out bound call -- I can debug the Java Rest server and see the call come in, and it executes as designed creating JSON to send out.  The problem is that I never get a call to the success function in the ajax call (I am not seeing the error function called either).

```
    urlrecent = "http://localhost:8080/server/api/recent/lake/" + handle + "/" + temp + "/" +  speed + "/" + degrees + "/" + lakekey;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: urlrecent,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("hello there!");
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
```

I have even tried a getJSON instead..no luck. In the mean time I will continue search Stack and the web for something that will work. I have tried a dataType of just "json" as well.

Thanks in advance.

=====

Yes, munged the contentType, but that didn't matter.

Comment: Why is `content-type` between quotes? And shouldn't it be `contentType`?

Comment: The success and error won't be called if you are calling cross-site. Not that cross site calls are easy to do when using localhost. For example, `http://localhost` and `http://192.168.1.100` may be the same machine but they are cross site.

Comment: Ok, if neither of the functions (success or error) are not called, obviously that is the behavior -- What does get called so that I can get my Json..

Answer (score 0):

Try it in IE8 and set `dataType: "html"`

```
urlrecent = "http://localhost:8080/server/api/recent/lake/" + handle + "/" + temp + "/" +  speed + "/" + degrees + "/" + lakekey;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "html",
        url: urlrecent,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("hello there!");
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
```

if you get syntex error at `data = JSON.parse(data)` or "hello there" in alert , it is encoding problem. In this case you should use `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8")`